# The use of Apache and MySQL windows services

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-services, xampp

From xampp control panel you can install Apache and MySQL as windows services.

What are the benefits or differences of running Apache and MySQL as windows services from running them without these services?

[image: xampp control panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These processes as Windows Server's services, get started when windows is restarted, and can be monitored and be operated as any other windows service.

Look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc)